# Selenium using different proxy for every tab

Tags: python, selenium, undetected-chromedriver

i want to use different proxies for every tab i open in my selenium driver.
In python.

Example (to explain what i want to do):

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
browser = uc.Chrome()
browser.get("https://stackoverflow.com") # First tab without proxy

# Opening the second tab

browser.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', 'tab2');")
browser.switch_to.window("tab2")
browser.get("http://google.com", proxy) # Second tab with proxy
```

I need help to know how I can do that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no support from Chrome or Firefox's APIs, your best option would be to use a different proxy for each chrome window

More information can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/#using-a-proxy)